# Use of constraints and Spatial indexes in Postgis

Tags: postgis, postgresql

We'are using Postgis to manage our geo data. They are coming from several sources, like Open street map, VPF, Shape and so on. We have defined constraints on the tables, and spatial indexes on geometry. When we perform big import or updates, it slows the process, so i drop constraints and index, do the big changes and when done i restore them.

Is it the good way to do it?

If not, is there other strategies? I've thought of using views, and defining key and index only on the views, but i don't know if it is a good idea (or even if it makes sense)

(Obviously I'm far from being a guru of PostgreSql or Postgis)

Comment: How do you import those data?

Comment: Yes, it  is a good strategy. It is generally faster to import without indexes and then add them. Obviously, you need to be sure your data is clean, you don't have duplicate records, invalid geoms, etc. But assuming that there is nothing wrong with your approach.

Comment: @zimmi: shapefiles are imported using the postgis script. VPF and Osm are imported using our own import tool.

Comment: @JohnBarça ok, thanks for the tip. About keeping indexes in separate views, does it make sense?

Comment: You cannot index a view. Indexes are a table property.

Comment: Yes, you're doing it right. For bulk changes it's better to not have indexes around. You speed up the process and the indexes you build at the end are cleaner and less bloated than if you had left the old indexes in place and updated.